# How to make sum(field)-sum(field2) and get a single result for all documents

Tags: mongodb, logstash-configuration

I have a mongodb collection that contains two fields, `amount` and `type`, in `type` i have either `cash-in` , `cash-out` or `transfer`. I want to add an index to elasticsearch with a new field which contains `(the sum of all cash-ins in each document) - (sum of all cash-outs in each document)` . ps: every line pushed either is a cash-in a transaction or a cash-out Everytime I add a new document the field should aggregate itself.
is there something like this

```
> if type="cash-in"
> mutate {
>   add_field => {
>     "cash-in" => "%{amount}"
>   }
> } 
> if type="cash-out"
> mutate {
>   add_field => {
>     "cash-out" => "%{amount}"
>   }
> } 
> 
> mutate {
>   add_field => {
>     "total" => "sum%{cash-in}-sum%{cash-out}"
>   }
> }
```

Comment: You just want to add one document to this new index which contains the "total" field?

Comment: i have a collection in mongodb that contains documents, each document ( a json file in es) contains fields within these fields i have a field called amount that states the amount of either a cash-in a trnsaction or a cash-out you can tell by the field type, i want to calculate the sum of (amount where type = cash-in) - sum (amount where type = cash-out)